# How to fix '[oh-my-zsh] plugin 'tldr' not found'?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr-node-client) under 'Command-line autocompletion' - but I still get

```
[oh-my-zsh] plugin 'tldr' not found
```

whenever I source .zshrc.

So I tried creating a "tldr" folder in .oh-my-zsh/plugins and putting bin/autocompletion.zsh inside, still does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install `tldr`? `npm` or `snap`? You *did* install it first, didn't you?

Comment: @Panki I used node, the tldr itself is working okay.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it linking the file from *node_modules/tldr/bin/completion/zsh/_tldr* to the plugins folder.

```
ln -s your_path_node_modules/node_modules/tldr/bin/completion/zsh/_tldr $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/tldr/_tldr
```

if you have already defined the path you could use -sf or delete the previous link and copy this file.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue (missing specific plugin) so I am unburying this thread ;)

In my case I fixed it by doing:

```
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh
git pull
```